# Solving initial value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Im solving initial value problem
$$ \frac {dy}{dx} + xy = xy^2; y(0)=3$$
After applying Bernoulli's equation method i obtained
$$ \frac {dv}{dx} -xv = -x$$
So, $$ p(x) = -x, q(x) = -x $$
For finding integrating factor 
$$u(x)=e^ {-\int xdx}=e^ {-\frac {x^2}{2}}$$
$$ y= \frac {\int u(x)q(x)dx+C}{u(x)}={\int u(x)q(x)dx}$$
So,
$$-\int xe^ {-\frac {x^2}{2}}dx $$
Please help further or guide me if i did something wrong.

Comment: $\int u(x) q(x) dx \ne - \int e^{-x^2/2} dx $.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it, how?

Comment: $q(x) = -x$, not $q(x) = -1$. Check all your steps. The integral can then be found in closed form.

Comment: Thanks i didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fine. the only point is $v=\frac1y$, so $y=\frac1v$ and 
$$u(x)v(x)-1\cdot\frac13=u(x)v(x)-u(0)v(0)=\int_0^x (u(t)v(t))'=\int_0^x u(t)q(t)dt=-\int_0^x te^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$$
So 
$$v(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(\frac13-\int_0^x te^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt\right),\hspace{10pt} y(x)=\frac{1}{v(x)}$$

Comment: How do we plug y(0)=3 in equation?

Comment: Since $v=\frac1y$, we have $v(0)=\frac13$ and I used it at the very beginning of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try separation of variables? This leads to a closed form solution that exists for all $x < \sqrt{2 \log \frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: In that case there is something wrong. If there is a closed form for $y(x)$, then we can find a closed form for $\int_0^x e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$, which does not exist.

Comment: there is an error in the original post, see my comments.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\mbox{Set}\ {\rm y}\left(x\right) \equiv {\rm f}\left(x^{2}\right)\equiv{\rm F}\left(x\right)
$$

> $$
> \mbox{You get}\quad {\rm F}'\left(x\right)
> ={{\rm F}^{2}\left(x\right) - {\rm F}\left(x\right)\over 2}
> $$